# Adding cc, bcc and attachment to email

Tags: php, email

I want to CC and BCC certain addresses in PHP's mail function, but the CC/BCC emails don't get delivered successfully.

```
<?php

$emailto = "umair.khan2313@yahoo.com,umair.khan666666@gmail.com";
$contacts = explode(",", $emailto);
array_walk($contacts, 'trim');

foreach($contacts as $contact) {
    $cc = "umair.khan1366@yahoo.com";
    $bcc = "amaan.khan13@yahoo.com";
    $tto = $contact;

    $tto. ="CC: $cc\r\n";
    $tto .= "BCC: $bcc\r\n";
    $subject = "hey";
    $body = "Test";

    $header = 'From: My Name <umair.khan666@gmail.com>'
        . "\r\n";
    $header = "CC: CC Name <$cc>\n";
    $header = "BCC: BCC Name <$bcc>\n";
    if(mail($tto, $subject, $body, $header)) {
        echo "SEND";
    }
}
```

How can to fix this?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: sir i want to add cc and bcc in this function they sould recieve email as a cc and bcc

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do that with your code. What is happening when you execute this code?

Comment: the email which i enter in cc and bcc is not receiving email

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate $header values. So just use "$header .=" instead of "$header ="

Comment: sir i added but email does not sent to that email which is in $header

Comment: @amaankhan Remove cc and bcc values from $tto and always end $header elements with "\r\n". Thus change $header = "CC: CC Name <$cc>\n" to $header = "CC: CC Name <$cc>\r\n"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy fix for your script -

Add the line break in fron of the first appended line:

```
$tto .= "\r\nCC: $cc\r\n";  # here is the change
$tto .= "BCC: $bcc\r\n";
```